# Javascript - Map data (and group by property) for multiple http requests inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a simple (I guess) mapping for an array inside a loop with multiple HTTP requests. In this case with VUE and `axios`.

In the first request I'm getting all the ProductGroups and then for each Distributor I make another call. I have 6 ProductGroups and 32 Distributors.

```
axios.get('/product-groups').then((res) => {
   res.data.forEach(pg => {
       this.distributor.forEach(d => {
          axios.get('/distributors/'+ d.id + '/product-data/' + pg.id).then((res) => {
              res.data.product_group = pg.name;
              this.pushToDataIn(res.data) //how this should look?
        });
    })
})
```

})

A ProductGroup is:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'PG1'
}
```

The result (`res.data`) is multiple objects coming in like:

```
{
 comments: "Something"
 distributor_id: 1
 last_year: 250938.74
 potential: 4549061.26
 product_group: "PG1"
 product_group_id: 107
}
```

Now, I want to push this data to an array based on `product_group` concatenating or adding some of the properties (in the same product group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the end-result you're aiming at, but to at least resolve the data, you can start with the following. Mapping that data to the required format shouldn't be too hard then.

The trick is always the same: map data to a list of promises and then `await Promise.all(...)` of that.

```js
// async fake product groups
// your: axios.get('/product-groups')
const getProductGroups = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 200, [
    { id: 1, name: 'PG1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'PG2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'PG3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'PG4' },
  ]);
});

// async fake distributor data
// axios.get('/distributors/'+ d.id + '/product-data/' + pg.id)
const getDistributorData = (dId, pgId) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 200, [{
    comments: "Something",
    distributor_id: dId,
    product_group_id: pgId,
  }]);
});

(async () => {
// distributors are given
const distributors = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Distributor 1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Distributor 2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Distributor 3'},
];

// await the product groups
const groups = await getProductGroups();

// map groups to promises
const groupPromises = groups.map(({id: pgId}) => {
  // map distributors to promises
  const distributorPromises = distributors.map(({id: dId}) => getDistributorData(dId, pgId));

  // resolve
  return Promise.all(distributorPromises).then(data => data.flat());
});

// await
const data = await Promise.all(groupPromises);

console.log(data);
})();
```

Comment: Yes, it helps. Thank you. But I have problems with mapping. How could I group the data variable based on a product group key? That was my concern...

Comment: @Tudor-RaduBarbu I updated the example. For now I simply switch the order, so that groups are used for the outer mapping. That way, the resulting data array will automatically contain one entry for each group, being an array of distributor data. If that's not what you need, you'll need to elaborate on the structure of the resulting data you need.